# ANTLR4 C Grammar parsing error for MACRO call

Tags: c, antlr4, context-free-grammar

Getting Parsing error in ANTLR4 C Grammar for the below code

```
   static const char* _store_error_msg(int err)
   {
     switch (err) {
        RETURN_ERROR_STRING(STORE_CLIENT_ERROR_NONE)
        RETURN_ERROR_STRING(STORE_CLIENT_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED)
     default:
        return "UNKNOWN_ERROR";
    }
   }
```

**Parse Tree generated as follows**

[image: Parse Tree]

If I change

```
expressionStatement
    :   expression? ';'
    ;
```

to

```
expressionStatement
    :   expression ';'?
    ;
```

I am able to remove parsing error but getting compilation error. What changes are required? Please help.

```
compoundStatement
    :   '{' blockItemList? '}'
    ;

blockItemList
    :   blockItem
    |   blockItemList blockItem
    ;

blockItem
    :   statement
    |   declaration
    ;

expressionStatement
    :   expression? ';'
    ;
```

Comment: If you get compilation errors, it's not strange that the ANTLR parser also produces errors, no? Shouldn't there be semi-colons after the `RETURN_ERROR_STRING(...)` calls?

Comment: @BartKiers, It is possible that RETURN_ERROR_STRING() macro definition might end with a semi-colon(;).. So, RETURN_ERROR_STRING(...) call without a semicolon at the end might be a valid statement.

Comment: Ah, OK, not too familiar with C. *"I am able to remove parsing error but getting compilation error"*: The compilation error you were talking about is apparently not the C compiler, but the ANTLR tool.

Comment: It is not possible to handle preprocessing and parsing in C using a single grammar. The code you'll feed into a C parser needs to be preprocessed already. Beyond your issue with semicolons, consider that `FOO(x +)` (or most other syntactic aberrations you might think of) may or may not be syntactically valid depending on how `FOO` is defined.